# Cloning a variable to add to list

Tags: c#, reference

I have code as follows:

```
var feeCTC = new FeeGroup(); feeCTC = feeGroup;
var feeWYS = new FeeGroup(); feeWYS = feeGroup;
feeCTC.FeeValue = 231;
firstList.Add(feeCTC);
feeWYS.FeeValue = 1269;
secondList.Add(feeWYS);
```

The problem I'm coming across is that once I get to the second calcuation that sets `feeWYS.FeeValue`, `feeCTC.FeeValue` is also updated to the same number (and so is its value in `firstList`), which leads me to believe that they are references to the same address. How do I clone `feeGroup` so that I can manipulate its values (and without using ICloneable interface)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feeCTC = feeGroup;` does NOT clone `feeGroup`.  It copies the *reference* to `feeCTC`.  So both `feeCTC` and `feeWYS` are referencing the *same object*.  That's why any changes you make thorugh one reference are reflected in the other reference.

> How do I clone feeGroup so that I can manipulate its values (and without using ICloneable interface)?

Some options:

- Write a clone method that copies the properties individually (making sure you close reference types as well)
- Write a copy constructor that does the same thing, just within a constructor.  One benefit of a copy constructor is that you can access private fields of both objects, which may be handy in some situations.
- Use [`Object.MemberwiseClone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx) to make a shallow copy (again making sure you close reference type properties.
- [Serialize the object to a memory stream and deserialize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects).

Note that `IClonable` is pretty well useless since all it defines is a `Clone` method but provides no implementation or context to indicate if the close is a shallow or deep clone.